# MoEngage Project Can't Compiled on React Native 0.73.2 and Java 17

Tags: react-native, kotlin, analytics, moengage

I have a react native `0.73.2` and working on MoEngage integration. The React Native version of MoEngage installed is `8.6.0` while the android sdk version is `com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:12.10.02`.

My React Native project is using Java 17 and there's an error while compiling the app:

```
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 17) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version. Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain * Try:
```

So, I update my (app) build.gradle

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
```

The problem persist, I still can't compile the app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this worked for me:

build.gradle

```
android {
  ...

  def agpVersion = com.android.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION
  if (agpVersion.tokenize('.')[0].toInteger() < 8) {
    compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
      jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
  }
}
```

References:

- https://expo.dev/changelog/2024/01-18-sdk-50
- https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/expo-modules-gradle8-migration.md#error-task-current-target-is-17-and-compilereleasekotlin-task-current-target-is-11-jvm-target-compatibility-should-be-set-to-the-same-java-version

Comment: Definitely will try this. My workaround before was editing the gradle file inside node_modules directly which is not a great solution.